# PHP Curl Function doesn't work

Tags: php, curl, instagram-api

I have some problem with the `curl` function. I am fetching Instagram posts with `curl`, but suddenly the function stopped working. I tried various changes but I can't make it work.

This is the function:

```
function cek($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();

    /**
     * Setup headers - I used the same headers from Firefox version 2.0.0.6
     * below was split up because php.net said the line was too long. 
     */
    $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
    $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
    $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank.

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10); /* Max redirection to follow */
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

    $html = curl_exec($curl); // execute the curl command
    curl_close($curl); // close the connection

    return $html; // and finally, return $html
}

function get_curl($url) {
    if(function_exists('curl_init')) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        echo curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
    } else {
        return file_get_contents($url);
    }
}
```

and this is where I call the function:

```
#$var = cek('https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'.instagram_tag.'/media/recent?client_id='.intagram_clientid.'&count=2');
$var = get_curl('https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'.instagram_tag.'/media/recent?max_tag_id=11&min_tag_id=1&access_token='.intagram_token.'&callback=?');

$cek = json_decode($var);
```

Comment: If `instagram_tag` is a variable, you have to prepend dollar symbol: `$instagram_tag` (and also for `intagram_token`... or maybe `instagram_token`?)

Comment: Without a more detailed error message, I would guess you have been blocked. Is there perhaps a limit on usage of the api?

Comment: $var = get_curl('https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'$instagram_tag'/media/recent?max_tag_id=11&min_tag_id=1&access_token='$intagram_token'&callback=?'); i tried that but it doesn't work @fusion3k

Comment: @jeroen i can see the JSON from instagram. so i don't think so I'm banned

Comment: That depends, it could be ip-based as well so the results from your computer and the server are not necessarily the same.

Comment: NOT `api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'$instagram_tag'/media/…` but `'api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' . $instagram_tag . '/media/…' ` OR `"api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'{$instagram_tag}/media/…" ` ... Have you tried  your url directly in browser? Also, check your error log to understand what is wrong

Comment: ok. can I use your token for test purpose? please remove yr last comment with token.

Comment: @fusion3k of course u can try . i'm deleting my comment

Comment: I would say Instagram is not stupid... Why are you using Googlebot/2.1 as useragent? Try to curl some other website and print the contents directly in the page. If it works, then most probably your server ip, or a combination of ip + useragent (among other possible combinations) are banned.

Comment: The script works fine. So, the problem is your url or - in effect - your ip, but it's sound strange, if your browser is on the same machine where your script is. Have you tried to retrieve (by script) the exact url you have pastes before in comment? (without variable, I mean)

Comment: @fusion3k Yes i tried but i tried in my computer.The script contain in my website.So i think my ip or my url is banned from Instagram 
you can look this link http://www.faven.com.tr/sosyal/php/instagram.php

Comment: please note: 1) in your site the error is `Call to undefined function get_curl`, so the problem is that `get_curl` is undefined. Anyway, I think that if your ip is banned, you probably get a message error.

Comment: @fusion3k Yey i totally agree with u. if i didn't see error message i will think about banned but i saw the error message. I'm confussed again. Thank u so much for your help by the way